# Can a piecewise smooth curve contain a straight line?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I have seen diagrams of piecewise smooth curves where this seems to be the case, but surely this means that the gradient function must be 0?

e.g. $C_2$ and $C_3$ in this image: https://complex-analysis.com/images/chp04/piecewise-smooth.svg

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the condition that the derivative not be zero.  For instance, the straight/horizontal line $\mathbf{r}(t)=\langle t, 4 \rangle$ has derivative $\langle 1, 0\rangle$ which is *never* the zero vector.

Comment: @Randall Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'Piecewise smooth' just means that its definition is broken into intervals, and it is smooth on the interior of each such interval (these segments must be joined up at the endpoints so that the overall functions is continuous). Of course, since straight lines are smooth, a piecewise smooth function can contain straight lines. In fact, it can consist solely of straight lines e.g. a 'zig-zag function':

[image: zig-zag function]

Image from [researchgate.net](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Zig-zag-function-Solution-to-the-nonlinear-boundary-value-problem-865_fig1_225979436)